# Initial value don't appear in formset field

Tags: python, django, initialization, modelform, formset

I'm working with Django 1.8.2 and I have a problem with the initial value of a field in a form in a model formset.

The model field is:

```
class md_changelog(models.Model):
    md_orderlog = models.ForeignKey(md_orderlog)
    controller_type = models.ForeignKey(ControllerType)
    # Other fields in the model
```

The form field is:

```
class md_changelogFormModel(forms.ModelForm):
    controller_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(label=("Controller Types"),
        widget=forms.Select, queryset=ControllerType.objects.all())
    # Other fields in the model
```

In the view the code is the following:

```
md_changelogFormSet = inlineformset_factory(md_orderlog,
                                            md_changelog,
                                            extra=len(appliances),
                                            form=md_changelogFormModel,
                                            formset=md_changelogForm,
                                            can_delete=False)

formset = md_changelogFormSet(
    initial=md_changelog.objects.filter(md_orderlog=order_id).values())
```

And when this formset is rendered all the data in the fields are present except controller_type.

Some idea about this?

Thanks!

Comment: I solved it using: formset = md_changelogFormSet(instance=order)